# React: Trigger re-render and re-calculation of offsetWidth after orientation change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile

### Problem:

I have a react photo app and the mobile view is wrong on orientation change.

If a user goes from portrait >> to landscape >> and back to portrait view, then the image is cut off. Until reload, then its displayed correctly.

This is because the image size is calculated with a scale that has the following calculation:

```
    const [scale, setScale] = useState(1)
    const wrapperRef = useRef(null)
    const box = useElementSize(wrapperRef)
    const orientationChange = useDeviceLandscapeOrientation()

    useLayoutEffect(() => {

        const wrapperNode = wrapperRef.current

        const verticalScale = wrapperNode.offsetWidth / width
        const horizontalScale = wrapperNode.offsetHeight / height
        const scale = Math.min(verticalScale, horizontalScale)

        setScale(scale)

    }, [box, width, height, orientationChange])
```

The problem is the offsetWidth. Only after reload or resize the `verticalScale` and `horizontalScale` adjust to the correct values for portrait view.

### My approach:

I can trigger a `window.location.reload()` that fires after a custom hook that listens for `orientationchange`. This works just fine. But I don't want to reload the full app as non-permanent data will be lost in that case.

I believe I am missing a trigger that re-renders the component and updates the scale / offsetWidth / offsetHeight accordingly.